# ¿Cómo creo una cadena a partir de una lista?

Tags: python, string, lista

He hecho un quiz con dos preguntas y sus opciones, todo funciona

```
wrong_answer = 0
user_answer = []
right_answer = 0



print("Q1. What is the capital of Norway?\na.Bergen\nb.Oslo\nc.Stavanger\nd.trondheim")
answer=str(input("Is it a, b, c or d: "))

if answer == "b":
    right_answer += 1
    
else:
    wrong_answer += 1
    user_answer.append("Q1. What is the capital of Norway? \nThe right answer is b. Oslo")
    
print("\nQ2. What is the currency of Norway? \na.Euro\nb.Pound\nc.Krone\nd.Deutche mark")
answer=str(input("Is it a, b, c or d: "))
if answer == "c":
    right_answer += 1
else:
    wrong_answer += 1
    user_answer.append("\nQ2. What is the currency of Norway? \n The right answer is c. Krone")
    print("Wrong")

print(f"\nYou have {right_answer} right answer. \n")
print(f"You have {wrong_answer} wrong answer")
print("\nThe right answer on the following question is:\n\n", user_answer)
```

hasta que hace uso del "user_answer" que al mostrar las respuestas me lo ejecuta con corchetes y comilla, y no me ejecuta el espacio (\n)

```
 ['Q1. What is the capital of Norway? \nThe right answer is b. Oslo', '\nQ2. What is the currency of Norway? \n The right answer is c. Krone']
```

Comment: supongo que lo que quieres es realizar un salto de línea, estás agregando una cadena a la lista, en esta se pierden los caracteres especiales, deberías guardar solamente las cadenas y después con un for recorrer la lista para mostrar sus elementos, suponiendo que haya entendido cual es tu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para lograr que tu lista se pase a string y respete los `\n` solo debes agregar `",".join(user_answer)`, es decir:

```
print("\nThe right answer on the following question is:\n\n", ",".join(user_answer))
```

Resultado:

```
The right answer on the following question is:

Q1. What is the capital of Norway? 
The right answer is b. Oslo,
Q2. What is the currency of Norway? 
The right answer is c. Krone
```